# python: can I use a string formatting operator with a class's getter methods?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, format, properties

I want to do something like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
        self._count = 0
    def getName(self):
        return self._name
    name = property(getName)
    def getCount(self):
        c = self._count
        self._count += 1
        return c
    count = property(getCount)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Foo %(name)s count=%(count)d" % self.__dict__
```

but that doesn't work because `name` and `count` are properties with getters.

Is there a way to fix this so I can use a format string with named arguments to cause getters to be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change it to not use `self.__dict__`.  You have to access `name` and `count` as properties instead of trying to access them by the names that their properties are bound to:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
        self._count = 0
    def getName(self):
        return self._name
    name = property(getName)
    def getCount(self):
        c = self._count
        self._count += 1
        return c
    count = property(getCount)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Foo %s count=%d" % (self.name, self.count)
```

Then in use:

```
>>> f = Foo("name")
>>> repr(f)
'Foo name count=0'
>>> repr(f)
'Foo name count=1'
>>> repr(f)
'Foo name count=2'
```

**EDIT**:  You can still use named formatting but you have to change your approach since you can't access the properties via the names you want:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "Foo %(name)s count=%(count)d" % {'name': self.name, 'count': self.count}
```

This *could* be better if you repeat things and/or have a lot of things, but it is a bit goofy.

Comment: I know I can do that, but I would rather used named arguments in the formatting string. I have a case where there's 6 or 7 fields rather than 2, and it's confusing to keep a list and a formatting string in sync.

Comment: @Jason yeah, unfortunately there's not a great way to do that, you have to access properties that way if you want to access them via the names `name` and `count`.  I added a sort of goofy way you could use name-formatting with still, it may be better for your needs, it may not.

Comment: +1: that's somewhat brute force (or "goofy" as you say), but very straightforward. Thanks!

Comment: A better way might be to define it using the dict constructor and keywords. At least that way you don't have to type so many quote marks! `... % dict(name=self.name, count=self.count)`